# Protect URL from URL typing while it should work when calling in iFrame using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, iframe, url-rewriting, url-routing

**Using Codeigniter**

So I have one page which I am calling in parent page using iFrame. Now I want to disabled access URL if that is being used outside the iFrame i.e in URL bar of browsers

Any idea about this?

Comment: as i know you cant check like that

Answer (score 0):

There is really no foolproof method to do this as an iframe isn't anything special just a webpage within a webpage. You could try adding a type of key that would be requested via get but that would require it being hard-coded in to the page and anyone could access it and view things outside the iframe if they wanted. If that doesn't matter to you then something like this will suffice:

URL:

> somecontroller/iframe?view=y

```
public function iframe() {

    if ($this->input->get('view') !== 'y') {
         exit('No direct script access allowed');
    }

}
```

**I would suggest getting the contents via ajax and populating a div with scrollbars (to mimic iframe). This way you can check if the item is a requested with ajax ("in iframe") and if not don't serve it.**

```
if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
   exit('No direct script access allowed');
}
```